# React, JSX and conditional display of components - TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, jsx

Can someone explain me, why this does not work?

```
import React from 'react';

import Dashboard from './../modules/Dashboard/';

const DashBoardPart = () => (
  <Dashboard>
    {false && <div>lorem</div>}
  </Dashboard>
);

DashBoardPart.propTypes = {};

export default DashBoardPart;
```

When I use such type of conditional display in this component, it throws this erorr:

> index.js:35 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'props' of null(…)

The component is also conditionally included in its parent component:

```
<LayoutMain>
            {!snTableMaximized && userData.type == constants.POSTPAID && <DashboardPart/>}
</LayoutMain>
```

I see the error only if the display condition is false. Also, such conditional display works fine in the parent component. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: somewhere you're accessing `this.props`, and `this` is presumably `null`. We will need more code to tell you where exactly it happens.

Comment: yep, it looks like what you say. I already solved it with a workaround. Thank you. but still...I am curious, why it does not work like this. that component is just simple div. why should react look for props in it? there are more components as children of dashboard and they do the same thing, when I try to conditionally render some of them. does it mean, the issue is in dashboard component itself?